# How to set TLS Certificates for a machine in docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

**What I want to do:**

I have dockerd running on one machine with TLS verify set to true. I would like to add this host as a machine in `docker-machine`

**What I have done:**

I used the following command to start dockerd:

```
$ sudo dockerd -D --tls=true --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H tcp://172.19.48.247:2376
```

On a second machine I sourced the following variables:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.19.48.247:2376                                                                                 
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/path/to/ssl
```

and ran docker command succesfully:

```
$ docker run busybox echo hello
hello
```

Then I added this host docker-machine:

```
docker-machine create --driver none --url=tcp://172.19.48.247:2376 dockerhost
```

**Where I am going wrong:**

I am getting a `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error now.

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME        ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                        SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS                                     Unknown   
dockerhost   -        none         Running   tcp://172.19.48.247:2376           Unknown   Unable to query docker version: Get https://172.19.48.247:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I tried using the `docker-machine config` but that doesnt work:

```
$ docker-machine config dockerhost --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H tcp://172.19.48.247:2376
Incorrect Usage.

Usage: docker-machine config [OPTIONS] [arg...]

Print the connection config for machine

Description:
   Argument is a machine name.

Options:

   --swarm  Display the Swarm config instead of the Docker daemon
flag provided but not defined: -tlsverify
```

Comment: Try moving dockerhost to the end of the command and not the start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the none driver will be configured to use the TLS certs found at `~/.docker/machine`. This isn't necessarily what is needed, because you'll run into the error you've run into if your remote Docker host has a certificate signed by something other than the ca.pem that you've got at that location.

I've found a reference to a workaround [here](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3212#issuecomment-201341733) that I tested and it definitely seems to work. Here are the steps I followed:

```
docker-machine create -d none --url tcp://remotedocker.example.com:2376 remotedocker
```

This creates the following directory:

```
~/.docker/machine/machines/remotedocker
```

Inside that directory is a file called `config.json`. Edit that file, and change every instance of ".docker/machine/certs" to ".docker/machine/machines/remotedocker"

Normally, when you access Docker remotely, it only needs to have access to the `ca.pem`, `cert.pem` and `key.pem` files. As far as I can tell, the other files referenced in `config.json` will likely not get used by the `none` driver because `regenerate-certs` is not implemented by `none`.

You will need to copy in the ca.pem and key.pem files

At this point, you should be able to run `docker-machine config remotedocker`, or `eval "$(docker-machine env remotedocker)"` and use your remote daemon successfully.